# JSON.parse: dataunexpected non-whitespace character json

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I use this script to generate autocomplete :

```
$('#ville').autocomplete({
    source : function(requete, reponse) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://<?=SERVERNAME.BASE_URL?>/autocomplete_villes',
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(x) {
                if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                    x.overrideMimeType("application/json");
                }
            },
            success : function(data){},
            error: function (xhr, status, text) {}         
        });
    }
});
```

but I have in console the error of unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON, how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in the server. Your script is expecting a JSON in return. And maybe your server is not sending a correct response.

Check if the `http://<?=SERVERNAME.BASE_URL?>/autocomplete_villes` is working correctly.